# How do i read this web logic log file - looking for response times

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

```
000.000.0.000 - foo_bar [11/May/2016:13:06:30 -0400] "POST /fooooooo/baaarrrrr HTTP/1.1" 200 10850669
```

This is weblogic HTTP log with no custom formatting and i'm having trouble figuring out what the 10850669 is and what the units are. I need to find response times...

Comment: The [common log format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) would point to that being the number of bytes returned.  You will not be able to get response times from this log as it is.

Comment: I really struggled to find documentation of what this was and I felt silly for asking. Where did you find it?

Comment: Most web services use the common log format.  It's been around forever - the link in my previous comment has references from 1995.

Comment: Duh, I dunno why my Google for common log format didn't pull that up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stdunbar mentioned, that's the common log format, which has bytes transferred rather than time taken.

If you want time taken, you can change to Extended log format in WL console

( xxx_domain > Summary of Servers > xxxxServer > Logging > HTTP )

click `advanced`, then change to Extended format.

Then you can put something like this in the extended logging format fields:

`c-ip date time time-taken cs-method cs-uri sc-status bytes` or whatever.

You probably need to restart the server afterwards.

More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/server.761/es_admin/src/tadm_logging_access_log.html).